# Information Security logo replaced by Server Fault logo

Tags: bug, status-completed

The Information Security logo has been replaced by the Server Fault one in all of the three top left drop down menus:

[image: Screenshot of achievements drop down, with Server Fault logo.]

The Server Fault logo seems to be the default blue box that is used for sites in beta. I suspect someone is already on this, and fixing it, but in case not I thought I should leave a note here.

**EDIT:** Since apparently this doesn't happen to everybody, here is some more info. I have tried on different devices on different networks (but all in the same country). I have refreched multiple times, and cleared the cache. The issue still persists. (Perhaps it is local to a specific CDN exit node? I have only tried from Sweden.)

And apparently our logo is not the only one messed up:

[image: Screenshot of multiple sites with wrong logo.]

Comment: Weird! What happens if you hit refresh? (Btw fwiw I don't see this behavior, but then I don't have any SF notifications... )

Comment: @AviD I'm not even a member of server fault. All of the notifications above are from IS. Added some more info in an edit.

Comment: Looks fine to me http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf3kV.png (that's our developer smoke test message, before you ask) - I expect this is just a CDN/cache glitch; if you do a hard refresh, does it go away?

Comment: marking complete; looks like Adam already gave it a kick

Comment: @MarcGravell The issue still persists for me, and according to comments on Meta.SE it does so for others. But I guess it is better to take it over there, so please do mark this as complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked Stack Exchange Meta, and the problem has an explanation there: [Site icons jumbled up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283807/site-icons-jumbled-up)

The problem is fixed now, at least for me. I had to clear the cache to get the right ones back, though. So if the problem persists for you, try that. So case closed, I guess.